# jquery datepicker set minDate and maxDate from jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jsp

Guys the following code allows the user to choose the date between september 1st to current date. i am having problem with jquery datepicker code. kindly let me know your views.

>

> <%    try         {
>                     sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
>
> ```
>               minDate = new Date();                       // timestamp now
>               Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();          // get   calendar instance
>               cal.setTime(minDate);                           // set cal to date
>               cal.set(cal.get(cal.YEAR),cal.SEPTEMBER,1);
>               minDate = cal.getTime();
>
>               maxDate = new Date();
>               cal.setTime(maxDate);
>               maxDate = cal.getTime();            
>       }   catch (Exception e)             
>       {
>
>               System.out.println(e);                  
>       }
>       %>      
>       <script type="text/javascript">
>           var mx = <%=sdf.format(minDate)%>;
>           var mv = <%=sdf.format(maxDate)%>;
>           $(document).ready(function(){
>               $("#revRepDate").datepicker({
>               showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly:
>                   true, buttonImage:
>               'style/images/icon_cal.png',
>                    dateFormat: 'yymmdd' });
>                   }); $("#revRepDate").datepicker('option',{minDate:mx
>                , maxDate:mv });
> ```

Comment: In a jsp page I imported both `java.util.Date` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, but when I use `var mx = '<%=sdf.format(minDate)%>';` I obtain the `sdf cannot be resolved` and `minDate cannot be resolved` exceptions. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need quotes:

```
var mx = '<%=sdf.format(minDate)%>';
var mv = '<%=sdf.format(maxDate)%>';
```

Comment: You can leave "guess" away. Javascript string variables have to be quoted anyway.

Comment: thanks ,  i have another problem , i want to show calendar from september 2010 to current date. for example consider if i am spoolin a report on 12th  january 2011 ,i should allow calendar selection from 1st september 2010 to 12th janyary 2011 . how to set the date to 1st sep 2010  from current date(if current date is january 11th 2011).

Comment: I didn't understand the 2nd question. Perhaps you can create a new question with it, providing a better explanation?

Comment: new question added http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087585/java-setting-date-to-previous-year-from-the-current-year