# Javascript setting Date to previous year from the current year

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

i want to show jquery calendar dates from 1st september 2010 to current date.

for example

consider if i am spooling a report on 12th january 2011 ,i should allow jquery calendar selection from 1st september 2010 to 12th janyary 2011 .My question is  how to set the date to 1st sep 2010 from current date (if current date is january 11th 2011) i.e next year. I want to get the date from the server and set in the javascript.

Currently i get the minimum  date from serverside java like this

```
minDate = new Date();                           // timestamp now
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();          // get calendar instance
cal.setTime(minDate);                           // set cal to date
cal.set(2010,cal.SEPTEMBER,1);
minDate = cal.getTime();
```

the output would be 20100901

but i dont want to hardcode 2010 in the code , i want a generic code that takes 1st sep 2010   as minimum even when i execute on january 2011.

Comment: Do you mean Java, or JavaScript?

Comment: he means both. He wants to output this to javascript. See his previous question. But the focus is on Java.

Comment: have you checked the documentation for Javascript `Date` objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Comment: if i run this code on january 2011 i will get 01 sep 2011 and not 01 sep 2010.

Comment: Then you're not going to be able to derive the date from whatever "today" is. You're going to have to store the date in a database or something.