# Set the datepicker mindate with the server date

Tags: jquery, jsp, date, datepicker

I would to set the datepicker mindate with the tomorrow date (server side, not client side).

I tried this [jquery datepicker set minDate and maxDate from jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086825/jquery-datepicker-set-mindate-and-maxdate-from-jsp) with an adding:

```
<% 
try { 
    Date now = new Date();  
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
    cal.setTime(now);  
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1); 
    Date tomorrow = cal.getTime(); 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

}   catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());               
}
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = '<%=sdf.format(tomorrow) %>';
```

but I obtain both `sdf cannot be resolved` and `tomorrow cannot be resolved` exceptions.

I imported both `java.util.*` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` in the jsp page:

```
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the [jstl](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSTL/JSTLFormatDate.htm)?

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core-rt" prefix="c-rt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

<c-rt:set var="now" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = '<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" type="both" timeStyle="long" dateStyle="long" />'; 
....
```

Comment: what's the difference between <c:set> and <c-rt:set>?

Comment: core-rt allows "<%=new java.util.Whatever()%>" to be set to a value.  [Reference](http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=7689)